# Group by matching a column of list or string with another list and create new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

so i have a data frame like:

---

| category | address | tags |

cat1        addr1    't1, t2, t3'

cat2        addr2    't4, t1, t3'

and so on

I have extracted the unique list of tags in a series.

I would like to have:

tags | category | address

t1      cat1       addr1
        cat2       addr2

t2      cat1       addr1

t3      cat1       addr1
        cat2       addr2

I am confused how t use `groupby` here? Or is it transform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

- [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) all columns without `tag`
- [`strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) trailing `'`
- [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) values to `DataFrame`
- reshape by [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html)
- `MultiIndex` to columns by [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)
- change columns order by [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html)
- [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) by column `tags`

---

```
df = (df.set_index(['category','address'])['tags']
        .str.strip("'")
        .str.split(', ', expand=True)
        .stack()
        .reset_index(level=2, drop=True)
        .reset_index(name='tags')
        .reindex_axis(['tags','category','address'], axis=1)
        .sort_values('tags'))
print (df)
  tags category address
0   t1     cat1   addr1
4   t1     cat2  adddr2
1   t2     cat1   addr1
2   t3     cat1   addr1
5   t3     cat2  adddr2
3   t4     cat2  adddr2
```

Comment: this is givin tags as 't1,t2,t3' cat addr per row. what i want is each tag t1, t2 etc has its own group

Comment: needed .str.split(',', expand=True) w/o space